# Selecting objects inside circle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to draw a Circle in google maps API, while still being able to select and drag objects inside it, as well as pan the map from inside it?

If I try to pan the map or drag an object from inside a circle, the circle moves instead. Polygons suffer this same issue, but this can be avoided by drawing Polylines in the shape of the polygon instead of the Polygon object; this allows you to drag the polygon from its edges, while not blocking objects inside it. I suppose one do something similar using trig to approximate a circle, but this seems like a poor solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `zIndex` or layering. Make sure that the objects that you want to be accessible in the polygon/circle objects have a higher `zIndex` attribute than the shape object itself. You can add the attribute when you create each object.

Comment: Thank you - setting the zIndex(es) allows selecting objects inside the circle. It looks like you can restore double/right click functionality inside the circle by duplicating the map listeners on the circle. No way to pan from inside AFAIK.

Comment: You can drag on the polygon as long as it's `zIndex` is below the map. For example, I have mine set at -1 which allows map drag to occur